# Date mapping or translation in ORACLE

Tags: oracle

I have to use a schema on the table FOOTRADE.
When I look for a specific tradeid, it works fine, in this case it returns 1/7/2020.

```
select FOODATE from CASPER.FOOTRADE where tradeid = '0000000001';
FOODATE
========
1/7/2020
```

However when I want to look for all the rows that contains foodate 1/7/2020  - I get an error ORA-01843: not a valid month

```
select * from CASPER.FOOTRADE  where TRADEDATE = '1/7/2020';
```

I suspect that the column is configured to somedate format and there has to be some mapping translation that needs to be done

Comment: try standard  literal `date'2020-07-01'` instead.

Comment: I get a "ORA-01843: not a valid month "

Comment: What is the datatype of the `TRADEDATE` column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming TRADEDATE is actually an oracle DATE type, then you should not use direct literals to compare.  Instead do:

```
where TRADEDATE = to_date('01/07/2020','MM/DD/YYYY');
```

The default date format mask is defined in [NLS_DATE_FORMAT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams122.htm#REFRN10119).  So if that format does not match with your input you get an error.  It is best to never assume what the default format may be on a system and do a to_date() call on the string.

Note that you can override the default and change the NLS_DATE_FORMAT for a session via:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY MM DD'  .. etc whatever mask you need.
```

Comment: I would say instead, you shouldn't compare directly with *string* literals.  Comparing with an explicit date literal (`date '2020-01-07'`) is fine.